# Could Not Evaluate Expression on deserialization of JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a really small JSON array object like this:

```
{
    "VehicleConfiguration": [
        {
            "VehicleUniqueID": 1000,
            "VehicleRegistrationPlate": "XXX5981",
            "VehicleType": 1,
            "VehicleGrossWeight": 3900,
            "VehicleTare": 900,
            "VehicleStart": "07:00",
            "VehicleEnd": "17:00",
            "MaxStops": 45,

        }
    ]
}
```

with some information on vehicles. Currently I am trying to read and deserialize only one vehicle.

I created a class for the JSON object:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class InputConfiguration
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleConfiguration")]
    public List<VehicleConfiguration> VehicleConfiguration { get; set; }
}
```

and another class for the configurations

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class VehicleConfiguration
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleUniqueID")]
        public int VehicleUniqueID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleRegistrationPlate")]
        public string VehicleRegistrationPlate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleType")]
        public int VehicleType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleGrossWeight")]
        public int VehicleGrossWeight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleTare")]
        public int VehicleTare { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleStart")]
        public string VehicleStart { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "VehicleEnd")]
        public string VehicleEnd { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MaxStops")]
        public int MaxStops { get; set; }
    }
```

but unfortunately, while deserializing through this code

```
private InputConfiguration ReadConfiguration(string configPath)
{
    string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(configPath);
    InputConfiguration config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputConfiguration>(jsonData);
    return config;
}
```

I get a VehicleConfiguration could not evaluate expression error.
I have tried everything, even array with only one value, yet nothing seems to surpass the error.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Answer to the question done by @Supun de Silva

```
public DataModel ReadFile(string inputPath)
{
    DataModel cache = new DataModel();

    cache.Config = ReadConfiguration(@"C:\Users\generic\Desktop\config.json");

    return cache;
}
```

That method returns cached data to main.

Comment: Just tried it and works totally fine.out of curiosity where is `private InputConfiguration ReadConfiguration(string configPath)` residing in your code ? and where does it get called ?

Comment: In a public class called InputReader, which returns cached data to the main program.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve], since it looks like it has to be something other than your code involved?

Comment: Here is what I recreated, it is hacked up code, but still works though https://github.com/supunt/temp_cs_json

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and Supun, thank you very much for your effort. I have created a minimal example, that even has the same references (using orTools by google, NPOI for excel reading/ writing and Newtonsoft for JSON) and it works. Although, in my original program doesn't work.
Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: if it is possible, put the original code in a public repo, then we can have a look.

Comment: It appears that something was wrong probably with the .Net version and the newtonsoft version (I cannot think anything else), because I transferred all the code of the project to a new project and now everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Good that you got it work. It happens sometimes that there are hidden issues like this. If you were to compare the original files with the new files, you might be able to spot the differences, but you might also just hope that it never occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work is a rebuild in debug mode, then a rebuild in release mode and then a rebuild in debug once again.
I do not understand why this hack works, but good enough.

Comment: Perhaps you have managed to make a reference to a dll, output from building one of your projects, instead of adding a reference to the project? ie, instead of adding a reference to project X, you added a reference to X\bin\Release\X.dll instead?